# Query code in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Can anyone explain this code in AngularJs?

This code inside `.factory` service

```
        'query': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            params: {fromDate: null, toDate: null}
```

Comment: Note: I use java in server language angularJs front page

Answer (score 0):

You have to show more code than this, however this is typically defining a property in an object which is an object itself containing all those properties.

For example it can be like this:

```
var temp = {
  'query': {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true,
        params: {fromDate: null, toDate: null}
  }
};
```

Then at some point (as a guess) it can be used to create a http request:

```
$.ajax(
   method: temp.query.method,
   url: 'some url',
   data: {temp.query.params},
   ...
);
```